# Can Valgrind catch all sorts of undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, valgrind, undefined-behavior

In other words can I be sure that my program is undefined behaviour free if it runs without any Valgrind error messages?

Comment: Of course not. Undefined beheviour does not necessarily manifest itself in any measurable way, i.e. it may well be *latent*.

Comment: As far as I know, valgrind does not detect if your girlfriend got pregnant.

Comment: If all undefined behavior were detectable, most of them would be defined instead. That's the problem.

Comment: It is clear that without valgrind UB is not detectable in general, but maybe some of them become detectable under valgrind?

Comment: Some of the errors that arise from UB will be detected by Valgrind, but since the input to Valgrind is executable code, it cannot detect that a piece of executable code was the result of compilation of source with UB.

Comment: For Clang/GCC, consider `-fsanitize=address,undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental error here.

Valgrind is not some sort of static analysis tool that understand the semantics of the C++ grammar and thus know when you are invoking *Undefined Behavior* as specified by the **C++ Standard**.

Valgrind is a tool that will however alert you whenever you are doing operations in the memory that are the results of the *Undefined Behavior* of your program. For example, it will detect whenever you access unallocated or freed memory, it will detect when you make a system call with an uninitialized (or partly unitialized) value/buffer, etc...

To take a medical analogy, Valgrind detects the **symptoms** of *Undefined Behavior*. The absence of symptoms does not imply the absence of *Undefined Behavior*.

Furthermore, because Valgrind only ever inspect code that runs, it will leave some "code" uninspected.

Getting rid of *Undefined Behavior* is extremely complicated. If your program is non-trivial, it is likely to be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. However, that should not prevent you from taking precautions:

- Turn on compiler warnings: `-Wall -Werror` is a given, `-Wextra` is great (in addition) for new codebases (**Elementary**)
- Use static analysis tools (several of them, since they do not report the same issues), Clang Static Analyzer, Purify, etc.. (*Good Practice*)
- Run Valgrind on an *extensive* test-suite (you can use `gcov` to check the coverage)(*Good Practice*)
- Read several Coding Standards, and *think* about their advice (do not apply them nilly willy), Sutter's come first, High Quality CPP or MISRA are much more stricter and extensive. Some automatic code review tools can check such a set of rules. (Nice, and rewarding on a personal level)

Once you've done all that, you've probably uncovered *most* of the *technical* errors within your program. Some, unfortunately, may be latent still. They may be exposed, one day, following a change of optimization options, a refactoring, or whatever... For stronger guarantees, you'll need another language.

Comment: +1 This carries the same message as my answer, but with more detail. I would like to add that valgrind will also detect errors that are not a result of UB.

Comment: @David: Could you precise ? I thought that all the memory issues it raise are considered UB; unless perhaps you're talking about the unitialized bits ?

Comment: For example, if you get a seg fault because another thread has just freed the memory you were about to write to, then that's not UB. Or is it?

Comment: @David: there are no threads in C++03 (...), in C++0x it would be UB.

Comment: @Mattieu Whilst there are no threads in C++03, there's nothing in the standard that says implementations can't support threading through libraries. Are you asserting that all errors found by Valgrind must be caused by UB?

Comment: @David: if Valgrind found an error for "legal" code, I think it would indicate a flow in the specification, don't you ?

Answer (score 5):

Once the program has been compiled, behaviour is defined. If you want to detect undefined behaviour you need to start earlier in the toolchain.

Undefined behaviour means that it is up to the compiler implementation to decide how to implement behaviour, the standard does not dictate what the behaviour must be. In other words, it's only meaningful to ask about UB for source code rather than compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

In  a word: no. Nothing -- not even valgrind -- is perfect.